Storybook decorator causing error in monorepo
I'm trying to add a global decorator to my Vite project. I'm using the following technologies:

Vite: Module bundler and runner
pnpm: Package manager. It's worth noting I am running the storybook command via npx as Storybook currently does not work with pnpx
nx: Monorepo

This the my Preview.tsx file used to implement the decorator:
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import { EtechUiProvider } from "etech-ui-utils";
import React from "react";

// Generated by Storybook
const preview: Preview  = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
}

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <EtechUiProvider configPath="./etech.config.ts" options={{ filter: "etech-ui-utils-tests" }}>
      <Story />
    </EtechUiProvider>
  )]

export default preview;


And here is my test Story:
Story:
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import Example from "../Example";
import React from "react";
import { EtechUiProvider } from "etech-ui-utils";

const meta: Meta<typeof Example> = {
  component: Example,
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof Example>;

export const Primary: Story = {
  args: {
    primary: true
  }
};


Component
import React from "react";

export default function Example() {
  return <h1>Example</h1>;
}

However, when I run this code I get the following error in the Storybook UI:

It shows the problematic dependency is a package called @ngrok/ngrok. This a sub dependency of another package universal-fs. This also being utilized in a package my monorepo etech-ui-utils. So here is what I have tried to fix it:
Remove references to @ngrok/ngrok in universal-fs via pnpm patch
This is not working for me somehow as ngrok can still be found in the pnpm-lock.yaml file. However, it is not being refernced anywhere.
Mark universal-fs as external
I've tried several variations of this. Here is my main.ts file for Storybook:
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-vite";
import { UserConfig } from "vite";
import { mergeConfig } from "vite";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: [
    "../../../../packages/**/stories/*.stories.tsx",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@chromatic-com/storybook",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-vite",
    options: {
      builder: {
        viteConfigPath: "../../../vite.config.ts",
      }
    },
  },
  viteFinal: (config: UserConfig) => {
    return mergeConfig(config, {
      optimizeDeps: {
        exclude: ["aws-sdk", "nock", "mock-aws-s3", "@ngrok/ngrok", "*.html"],
      }
    });
  }
};
export default config;


Still no luck there.
What is going wrong here?
